# How to use single sign on authentication (SSO) in Desktop sideload UWP app?

Tags: uwp, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, openid-connect, desktop-application

Can anyone help for how to implement Single sign on authentication (SSO), with open id connect in side load UWP Desktop app.

I have tried using [Auth0](https://auth0.com/), it get authenticate but it needs redirect URL, which is pass the app call back URL using `WebAuthenticationBroker.GetCurrentApplicationCallbackUri()` where the call back URL start with `ms-app://`. After successful login, the app is redirecting to Microsoft store.

I have also tried `WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(WebAuthenticationOptions.None, authStartURI);` but no luck.

> **Note:** This is the UWP Desktop sideload application.

Answer (score 0):

In the desktop application it's difficult to use OIDC without an embedded browser, when you request for a token you need a callback where the identity provider will sent you the token, and there is no way to do that in the dektop application unlike mobile application.
In your case you need an embedded browser that can handle http callback for you